# É possível editar o nome de um projeto?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

É possível alterar o nome de um aplicativo depois de já criado o projeto no Android Studio, pela Manifest o algo assim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim.

Basta alterar o android:label="@string/app_name" no nó application em AndroidManifest.xml pelo nome que você quiser colocar.

Exemplo:

```
   <application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="allowBackup">
```